# Oracle to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I've been using oracle database and I want to switch to using Mysql
some of the commands in sql plus used in oracle database don't work here

like

```
&&dept
```

or

```
&'dept'
```

Comment: Copied from @PhiterFernandes deleted answer: [50 Things You Must Know Before Switching From Oracle to MySQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/03/13/50-things-to-know-before-migrating-oracle-to-mysql/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it as

```
@@dept or @'dept'
```

[User Defined Variables in Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

Answer (score 1):

[This is a list of 50 things you must know before switching from Oracle to MYSQL.](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/03/13/50-things-to-know-before-migrating-oracle-to-mysql/)

Comment: "The problem is all inside your head", she said to me / "The answer's easy if you take it logically" / "I'd like to help you in your struggle to be free" / "There must be 50 ways to leave your database"  :-)